# Fiware Orion performance variations

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I need advice on matter of performance.

Issue is that posting exact same data to Fiware Orion with only difference being Fiware-Service path result in exponential increase in times. Meaning each next request take more time than first and keep on adding.

My program read and parse some files then store that into Fiware Orion, depending on file size it take up to max 3 seconds to do checks and parsing. 
Then that data is being send to Orion Context Broker.

Example:

- Empty and fresh instance of Orion
- Test case here is 3000 entities, POST using batch operations.
- Because of size of entities that 3000 are being cut into smaller sizes and send to Orion with batch. In this case my program will cut them into size of 500 and send them one after another.
- First run 3000 entities time for completing operations 7 second.
- Change service path run same 3000 entities time for completing operation 14/15 seconds.
- Change service path run same 3000 entities time for completing operation 20 + seconds.
- etc..

My instance of Fiware is being run using docker-compose commands used for Fiware/Mongo:

`-dbhost mongo -reqMutexPolicy none -dbPoolSize 100 -logLevel NONE`

`--nojournal --logappend`

I need advice on this since i didn't found specific info about this type of issue (if i missed please just point me to it). For me it seem like something is with mongo making it behave strange. Or could it be i am making some mistake.

```
{ id: "8B56C6",
type: "DepositPoint",
family: { value: "Agent", type: "String", metadata: {} },
serialNumber: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
refSortingType: { value: "sortingtype:2", type: "String", metadata: {} },
description: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
refType: { value: "depositpointtype:0", type: "String", metadata: {} },
storedWasteOrigin: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
location:
{ value: { type: "Point", coordinates: [Array] },
 type: "geo:json" },
address: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
fillingLevel: { value: 0, type: "Integer" },
cargoWeight: { value: 0, type: "Integer", metadata: { unit: [Object] } },
temperature: { value: 0, type: "Integer", metadata: { unit: [Object] } },
methaneConcentration: { value: 0, type: "Integer", metadata: { unit: [Object] 
} },
regulation: { value: "Municipal association", type: "String", metadata: {} },
responsible: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
owner: { value: "Txorierri", type: "String", metadata: {} },
dateServiceStarted: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
dateLastEmptying: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
nextActuationDeadline: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
actuationHours: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
openingHours: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
dateLastCleaning: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
nextCleaningDeadline: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
refDepositPointIsle: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
status: { value: "ok", type: "String", metadata: {} },
color: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
image: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
annotations: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
areaServed: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
dateModified: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} },
refDevice: { value: "", type: "String", metadata: {} } }
```

I re post this since same question got deleted without any reason. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the Fiware-Service-Path and use a custom attribute to group your entities. An interesting attribute defined by schema.org is areaServed https://schema.org/areaServed which could be used for those purposes.